# Validation of multiple viewmodels inside the same ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. I have an ActionResult that accepts requests from clients, and I am attempting to employ MVC validation and model-binding magic. This action does not return a view, but redirects to other actions as per certain logic.

My issue is that there are different types of requests that are associated with different models, and these models are mutually exclusive.

example:

```
class Model1
{
    [Required]
    public string PropA;
}

class Model2
{
    [Required]
    public string PropB;
}
```

The logic inside the ActionResult would follow something along the likes of:

```
     If Model1 is valid then RedirectToAction("A")
     Elseif Model2 is valid then RedirectToAction("B")
     Else RedirectToAction("ERROR")
```

What is the best practice for implementing this type of functionality, or something similar in ASP.NET MVC4?

Comment: Since you have an `if` in your controller action already, why don't you just check if the field is valid there? Combine the two fields into one model and then just see if `PropA` or `PropB` is not `null`. I don't think the MVC validation stuff is buying you anything here.

Comment: The example provided was meant to be very simple, in actuality the models have a lot of properties with complex validation rules.

Comment: Right, but if you just drop all of the `[Required]` attributes and do the not `null` check inside the controller action, that should be the same.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and that would definitely work. I guess I was wondering if there was a way to use the standard validation attributes and just validate more than 1 model inside the same ActionResult in order to save some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a validationcontext and validate each viewmodel in your controller. You'd have to do the following for each viewmodel:

```
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();     
var context = new ValidationContext(myObject);
bool validationPassed = Validator.TryValidateObject(myObject, context, validationResults, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the modelstate and see if it has and errors from inside the controller:

```
bool hasErrors =  ViewData.ModelState.Values.Any(x => x.Errors.Count > 1);
```

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470776(v=vs.108).aspx

[2] http://forums.asp.net/t/1480118.aspx/1